# Can the SARS‑CoV‑2 virus mutate in people who have been fully vaccinated?

Tags: microbiology, virology, mutations, coronavirus, covid

I am curious to know if the original SARS‑CoV‑2 virus, or any of its variants, can mutate in people who have been fully vaccinated. I am referring to those people who have received all the recommended vaccinations and booster vaccinations since the worldwide outbreak of COVID-19 back in November 2019.

Can SARS‑CoV‑2 mutate in people who have been fully vaccinated?

Comment: I wonder if we also can say something about expected mutation _rates_ between vaccinated and unvaccinated, or even the kind of mutations that are likely to happen in each case.

Comment: Most likely there is little effect. See last (new) ¶ of my answer.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Please see [my comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/191881) on Ben's post.

Comment: I don't know "anything" in mutation, but if a virus is not "killed" (with or without vaccination), mutation can occur and can be transmitted ... It is a logical "defensive" reaction. Do we know all about "virus"? No, and in reality, about "nothing".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since vaccination is not 100% protective against infection (i.e. the virus can sometimes succeed in establishing and replicating in a vaccinated host's body), the answer is yes. Furthermore, since vaccination is also not 100% protective against transmission — although it does lower the probability of transmission from infected individuals — such mutations could also be transmitted to other hosts.

However, vaccination greatly reduces the probability of infection and onward transmission. It might also be expected to reduce the duration and intensity (viral load) of infection, which would further reduce the probability that a mutation arises in an infected person (because the total number of mutations is proportional to the population size of the virus within the host).

Singanayagam et al. (2021) found that the peak viral load was *not* greatly reduced in infected, vaccinated people infected with the delta variant (relative to unvaccinated people), but that the decline from the peak was faster; with more effort/re-analysis of these data, we could estimate the magnitude of the change in the expected total number of viral replications over the course of an infection, which would in turn tell us the expected proportional difference in overall mutation  probability due to changes in the within-host dynamics of the infection. (Also see [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/105393/25523) for more detail on viral load in vaccinated vs. unvaccinated individuals.)

Responding to a comment: the mutation *rate* (i.e. per base pair per viral replication, or per genome per viral replication), and the mutational spectrum (i.e. what kinds of mutations occur) are not expected to change much under vaccination - these are determined by the biochemistry of viral replication, and are probably not affected by what the host's immune system is doing.

(Disclaimer: my background is in ecology/evolution/epidemiology, not virology or immunology or biochemistry.)

---

Singanayagam, Anika, Seran Hakki, Jake Dunning, Kieran J. Madon, Michael A. Crone, Aleksandra Koycheva, Nieves Derqui-Fernandez, et al. “Community Transmission and Viral Load Kinetics of the SARS-CoV-2 Delta (B.1.617.2) Variant in Vaccinated and Unvaccinated Individuals in the UK: A Prospective, Longitudinal, Cohort Study.” The Lancet Infectious Diseases 0, no. 0 (October 29, 2021). https://doi.org/10.1016/S1473-3099(21)00648-4.

Comment: +1 - Of course you are aware of this, but it seems like the OP may not be - but it may be worth clarifying that viruses mutate whenever they replicate, entirely independently of whether they are in a host that has been vaccinated - the vaccine doesn't precent mutations, just (as you said) reduces the opportunity for them to replicate and mutate.

Comment: If someone wants to leave a reason for their downvote I would be happy to try to respond.

Comment: My background is chemistry but your answer seems pretty logical. I would resume it with the fact that vaccination results in a faster decay of the number of virus particles within one's body. How many enter the body and their business within should be independent of our immune response.

Comment: I did not downvote but I **do not agree** with your claim that "*the mutational spectrum [...] are not expected to change much under vaccination - these are determined by the biochemistry of viral replication, and are probably not affected by what the host's immune system is doing.*". That is completely false; because *of course* the mutational spectrum depends on the immune system; if it is good at destroying a certain viral strain then **of course** the virus population would mutate *away from that strain*!

Comment: @user21820, what you are describing is within-host selection, not a change in the mutational spectrum. Perhaps that process should be included in my answer, but it's not technically mutation.

Comment: @BenBolker: Yes, within-host selection is not mutation, but I didn't say that it is. What I said is that the mutational **spectrum** is affected by the host immune system characteristics. It would be best if you fix that issue with your post.

Comment: @user438383: Sorry, but I don't think you know what you are talking about. The only way we can scientifically determine mutational spectra (to within a given confidence level) is via **population-based** statistical sampling. For example, each carcinogen leads to certain spectrum of frequencies over the various kinds of mutations, on a **statistical** basis. Comparing with a baseline spectrum lets us statistically deduce the mutational spectrum of a particular carcinogen being tested.

Comment: @BenBolker: It occurs to me that you may have a differing interpretation of "spectrum". No doubt the immune system is unlikely to directly affect the actual mutation process, but the resulting spectrum is all we can observe; we can never observe the actual mutations, and it is largely irrelevant to the topic at hand. Even in the case of carcinogen mutational spectra, some spectra are due to error-correcting mechanism failures. Are you going to say that those are not the true spectra just because the carcinogen didn't affect the actual mutations or DNA-breakages?

Comment: Of course vaccination in an ongoing pandemic influences what can spread out more. I think you are both right but taking different aspect. Modesty, I am not specialist at all, I have interpreted the question as for what happen "inside". So the virus can mutate but it has less time / less population. Anyway my interest is mostly dictated by the time being. Unfortunately.

Comment: @user21820: The mutational spectrum _isn't_ affected by the characteristics of the host's immune system.  The ways in which the virus mutates are totally unaffected - the only thing that changes is which of those mutations are selected for or against once they appear.

Comment: @Vikki: That's what you **assume**. You, like all the others making your claim, have not a single bit of evidence, because the virus **uses the host's cellular mechanisms** in order to replicate, and those mechanisms **are affected by the immune system**.

Comment: @user21820: The cellular mechanisms _**which the virus uses in order to replicate**_ (basically just the cellular translation machinery and the cell's supply of high-energy nucleoside triphosphates) are **not** affected by the immune system, and **you** have yet to provide a single bit of evidence that they **are**.

Comment: @user21820 : I really hesitate to get into this, but those of us you are arguing with (me, Vikki, user438383) have the weight of convention and standard definitions on our side. Yes, you **could** define "mutational spectrum" as "the set of alterations in gene sequence observed between the infecting genome and the genomes transmitted to new hosts", but that's not how it is defined in the literature. While it's not physically or biochemically impossible for immune processes to affect the process of viral replication and thus change the mutational spectrum ...

Comment: ... it's not a phenomenon that, as far as I know, has ever been observed or speculated to be a plausible outcome. Feel free to post an answer of your own if you like -- I'm going to disengage from the debate now.